# Fastest way to fetch 2000 random documents from 10 millions of documents in Atlas(remote_DB) and save it as list using PyMongo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I want to fetch between 800-2000 random documents repeatedly from 10 million documents in remote DB using `pymongo` and convert the `cursor` to a `list`. I tried sample `aggregation` query but it takes a lot of time (30-45 seconds or a minute) depending on load. Is there any fastest way possible to fetch random documents and convert the cursor to a list as quickly as possible?

I tried this :

```py
import random

load = random.randint(800, 2000)

random_profiles = list(profiles.aggregate([{"$sample": {"size": load}}]))
```

Comment: Do you need to return the entire document, or can you get by with a `"$project"` after `"$random"`?